# Cannot Map Inherited Generic Collection Properly

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to map a collection of objects with an additional property that derives from the generic `List<T>` class.  I've tried numerous different configurations, but they all either return only the items in the collection and not the properties of the derived class, or only the properties and not the items.

I seem to be missing something in the mapping configuration.  I've seen examples of using AfterMap in earlier versions of AutoMapper - but any attempt I have had at these has resulted in a stack overflow.

Below is my code with some different configurations that I have tried.

This is using AutoMapper 8.0.0/8.1.1.

```
public class InheritedList<T> : List<T>
{
    public string Property { get; set; }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Collection Items are mapped; InheritedList.Property is not mapped
        var configuration1 = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<string, int>()
               .ConstructUsing(s => s.Length);
        });

        // Collection Items are not mapped; InheritedList.Property is mapped
        var configuration2 = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<string, int>()
               .ConvertUsing(s => s.Length);

            cfg.CreateMap<InheritedList<string>, InheritedList<int>>();
        });

        // Collection Items are not mapped; InheritedList.Property is mapped
        var configuration3 = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<string, int>()
               .ConvertUsing(s => s.Length);

            cfg.CreateMap<InheritedList<string>, InheritedList<int>>();

            cfg.CreateMap<List<string>, List<int>>()
               .Include<InheritedList<string>, InheritedList<int>>();
        });

        // Collection Items are not mapped; InheritedList.Property is mapped
        var configuration4 = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<string, int>()
               .ConvertUsing(s => s.Length);

            cfg.CreateMap<List<string>, List<int>>();

            cfg.CreateMap<InheritedList<string>, InheritedList<int>>()
               .IncludeBase<List<string>, List<int>>();
        });

        IMapper mapper = new Mapper(configuration1);

        var source =
            new InheritedList<string>
            {
                Property = "Test"
            };

        source.Add("ABC");
        source.Add("ABCDEFG");

        var destination = mapper.Map<InheritedList<string>, InheritedList<int>>(source);

        Console.WriteLine(destination.Count);
        Console.WriteLine(destination.Property);
    }
}
```